# I want to appeal this problem from an exam in Linear Algebra I, do you think its appealable?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

I have the follow question :

Let $U_1, U_2, W$ are linear spans of linear space $V$ while V is finite.

Proof:

If $$U_2 \cap W \neq \{0\}$$
$$U_1\cap W\neq \{0\}$$
$$U_1 \cap U_2=\{0\}$$

Then $dimW \geq 2$

My proof :

Since $U_1 \cap W \neq \{0\}$ there is a least one $v$ that $v \in Sp\{U_1 \cap W\}$ impiles $v \in Sp\{U_1\}$ and $v \in Sp\{W\}$

In a similar way since $U_2 \cap W \neq \{0\}$ there is a least one $u$ that $u \in Sp\{U_2 \cap W\}$ impiles $u \in Sp\{U_2\}$ and $u \in Sp\{W\}$

Let $u_1,u_2$ be any vectors so that $u_1 \in Sp\{U_1 \cap W\}$ and $u_2 \in Sp\{U_2 \cap W\}$.

If the group $\{u_1,u_2\}$ is linear dependent then we get a contradiction to $U_1 \cap U_2=\{0\}$

Therefore we proof that for all $u_1 \in Sp\{U_1 \cap W\}$ and to all $u_2 \in Sp\{U_2 \cap W\}$ Therefore $\{u_1,u_2\}$ is linear independent therefore we proved the existence of $u \in Sp\{W\}$ and $v \in Sp\{W\}$, and from the proof above we know that $\{u,v\}$ is linear dependant, therefore we get $dimW \geq 2$

For some reason the examiner, has marked this line

If the group $\{u_1,u_2\}$ is linear dependent then we get a contradiction to $U_1 \cap U_2=\{0\}$

And wrote why? This claim requires a proof. and I got 7/12 point for this question.

I think this is trivial and also from the proof above it's clear that I understand why this statement is true.

I'd be very happy to hear from examiners of linear algebra exams, do you think this is appealable? or do you think that this is justified?

Since the grade can go down or up then I appeal I'd like to consult about this matter first.

I really appreciate any help, Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure this is a question about *mathematics* so much as a question about *grading* since the underlying thought seems to be, "Is my proof explicit enough [for a specific course]?" which isn't a universally applicable question. The people who can answer it for you would be those who are in charge of your course and you should ask them.

Comment: @Milo Brandt I beg to differ, I think this is a mathematical question, since I ask if my proof is well constructed and detailed enough to be considered as perfect, hence to receive all the point of the question, I'd ask the people in my course, but I learn at an Open University, therefore I cannot ask those in charge of the course, unless I appeal, meaning I take a risk and I want to see people with higher knowledge in mathmatic agrees with me, before I do so.

Comment: "I think this is trivial and also from the proof above it's clear that I understand why this statement is true." I disagree. It is simple, but not entirely trivial at your level, and I don't see anything earlier that indicates to me that actually understood that. One thing that you have to understand is that there are a tremendous variety of misunderstandings students have when learning a course. If you ever teach, I promise you will be amazed at what they will think (one student told me he had trouble with math "because it isn't logical".) Your instructor doesn't know if you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well first complete the proof.

$ \{ u_1, u_2 \} $ linearly dependent implies $\alpha u_1 = u_2 $ so then $u_2 \in U_1 \cap U_2$ hence contradiction.

I think the marker was harsh as you don't really need much of an argument to prove the statement. Everything else seems fine so there is no worry that your mark will go down.

However do try and see the markers point of view, it is an easy question where not much work is required and being worth so many marks it may be expected that every step is necessary.